# SQL INSERT INTO with Multiple SELECTS From Different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I am attempting to Insert rows with data from 2 tables. The first table is my users AspNetUsers and the second table AspNetUserRoles. I want to give all users the same role. I have tried the following:

```
  INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] ([UserId], [RoleId])
  SELECT (SELECT Id FROM [MyDB].[dbo].AspNetUsers) AS UserId,
 (SELECT Id FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[AspNetRoles] WHERE Name = 'Intermediary') AS RoleId
```

I get the error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

This is because the query is selecting all the users, which I want, but my SQL needs to be modified to insert each user and the same RoleId.

I think I might need to use a cursor, or how should I go about this? I am using MS SQL Server.

Comment: do they have any matching fields

Comment: Why shouldn't you use stored procedure?

Comment: One of the inner sub-queries returns more than one row. Skip the sub-queries, do joins instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] 
    ([UserId], [RoleId])
SELECT 
    Id,
    (SELECT Id FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[AspNetRoles] WHERE Name = 'Intermediary') AS RoleId
FROM
    [MyDB].[dbo].AspNetUsers
```

as long as `WHERE Name = 'Intermediary'` return 1 row.

Comment: Works if it's assumed there's only one Id for 'Intermadiatery'. Small improvement would be ....SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM .. at the inner select -query.

Comment: There is only 1 Id for Intermediary. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way

```
INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]
            ([UserId],[RoleId])
SELECT ANU.Id AS [UserId],
       ANR.Id AS [RoleId]
FROM   [MyDB].[dbo].AspNetUsers ANU
       CROSS JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[AspNetRoles] ANR
WHERE  ANR.NAME = 'Intermediary'
```